# Setup passwordless sudo for ubuntu user in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am moving from AWS to Digital Ocean and I am used to the ubuntu user having sudo access without entering the password. How can I replicate this?

Also what are the security implications of having this enabled?

Comment: that just protected your computer from malware to get root permission

Comment: @damadam Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 5):

Add the user to

```
/etc/sudoers
```

with

```
sudo visudo
```

and add

```
{user} ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

where {user} is the user your want this for. Mind that you can break your system if you do this wrong so make sure to always has a 2nd account logged into "root" (so with a prompt `#`, not `$`)

> Also what are the security implications of having this enabled?

Serious.

You should be using ssh keys anyways regardless of this. Besides that anyone with access to the system can destroy it. 1 rule of cloud instances: you make backups. Always. Every time. Instances are volatile so they can get deleted at any time without warning. So you make backups. Always. Every time. That helps recovering when you yourself makes mistakes but always when others mess your system up.

Comment: +1 just for this best answer at this question, summarised in 1 word :D

Comment: "You should be using ssh keys anyways regardless of this. Besides that anyone with access to the system can destroy it. 1 rule of cloud instances: you make backups. Always. Every time. Instances are volatile so they can get deleted at any time without warning. So you make backups. Always. Every time. That helps recovering when you yourself makes mistakes but always when others mess your system up."   So why does AWS launch them with Ubuntu having passwordless sudo by default?  Do most people change it?

Comment: No idea. We did (we have lots of google instances) but it depends on your other security measures. Our dashboard entrance to the cloud we locked down to 2 systems and a recovery method. Our instances are not accessible from outside our company except when we follow a procedure where 2 people each have 1/2 of a key that is invalid on using.

Comment: Gotcha, also one thing that tripped me up is that I had to add `<username> ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` to the bottom of `sudo visudo`' file in order for it to work.  I was adding in the middle at first.

Comment: One addition: ssh keys is your 1st defense against remote intrusions. The sudo password is your last defense. For LOCAL intrusions sudo password is your ONLY defense but it is also a WEAK one: it is easy to retrieve your admin password with alterations of user owned files (so those are editable).